# Python 3.6 new line with user input

Tags: python

Made a program that allows the user to enter some text and have a text file be created with that text inside it. However, when the user puts \n it doesn't start a new line. Finding it very difficult to use my program to create text files as it writes all the text on one line lol

Thanks

EDIT - Sorry. Here is my code (Just the part we are concerned with).

```
class ReadWriteEdit:
    def Read(File):
        ReadFile = open(File,"r").read()
        print(ReadFile)
    def Write(File, Text):
        WriteFile = open(File,"w")
        WriteFile.write(Text)
    def Edit(File, Text):
        EditFile = open(File,"a")
        EditFile.write(Text)

def Write():
    print("WRITE")
    print("Enter a file location / name")
    FileInput = input("-:")
    print("Enter some text")
    TextInput = input("-:")
    ReadWriteEdit.Write(FileInput, TextInput)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found, special escaped characters are not interpolated in strings read from input, because normally we want to preserve characters, not give them special meanings.

You need to do some adjustment after the input, for example:

```
>>> s=input()
hello\nworld
>>> s
'hello\\nworld'
>>> s = s.replace('\\n', '\n')
>>> s
'hello\nworld'
>>> print(s)
hello
world
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add your input to the variable. You didn't provide any code so I'll just have to improvise:

```
data = open('output.txt', 'w')
a = input('>>')
data.write(a + '\n')
data.close()
```

But the better solution would be, like the comment below me mentioned, to use `sys.stdin.readline()`

```
import sys
data.write(sys.stdin.readline())
```

Comment: You can also use sys.stdin.readline() (call `import sys` first). The will append the newline for you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (dirtiest?) way IMHO is to print the message and then use input() without a prompt (or with the last part of it)

```
print("Are we REALLY sure?\n")
answer = input("[Y/n]")
```

Comment: Quick and easy, perfect for my use case. Thanks!